# The set$\quad${${E(R/I)|I\leq R}$}$\quad$contains an isomorphic copy of each indecomposable injective.

Tags: modules, injective-module

I am reading Rings and Categories of Modules by Anderson and Fuller. In the book page 293:

> An indecomposable injective left $R$-module must be the injective envelope of each of its non-zero submodules.It follows that the set$\quad${${E(R/I)|I\leq R}$}$\quad$contains an isomorphic copy of each indecomposable injective.

I want someone to explain why the set$\quad${${E(R/I)|I\leq R}$}contains an isomorphic copy of each indecomposable injective. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $E(-)$ denotes injective envelopes, and $I \leq R$ means $I$ is a left ideal of $R$.

Recall Lemma 25.2 on page 290 in Anderson-Fuller. It says $M$ cogenerates $R/I$ iff $I$ is the annihilator of $M$. We apply this to our situation.

Take any indecomposable injective $E$, and let $I \leq R$ be its annihilator. 
Then $E$ cogenerates $R/I$ by the lemma. 
That implies there is a monomorphism $\iota \colon R/I \to E^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Take a projection $\pi \colon E^n \to E$ such that $\pi \iota \neq 0$. 
Then the composition induces a monomorphism $(R/I) /\ker(\pi \iota) \to E$. 
Since $E$ is the injective envelope of all of its submodules, this shows $E$ is isomorphic to the injective envelope of $(R/I) /\ker(\pi \iota)$, which is a factor module of $R$.

Comment: If E cogenerates R/I,then R/I is isomorphic to a submodule of $E^{A}$ not E.

Comment: You are right, I was i bit careless there. However I think this can be repaired. Compose $R/I \to E^A$ with a projection to  $E$ such that the composition is non-trivial, and kill the kernel of the composition. Do you think that could work?

Comment: Yes,you are right.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much easier proof.

Assume that $A \neq 0$ is an idecomposable injective right $R$-module. Let $x\in A$ be any nonzero element. Since $E(xR)$ is injective, then $E(xR) \subseteq^{\oplus} E(A)$ (i.e., $E(xR)$ is a summand of $E(A)$). But $A$ is injective. So, $E(A)=A$ and thus $E(xR) \subseteq^{\oplus} A$. Since $A$ is indecomposable and $E(xR) \neq 0$, then $A=E(xR)$. But $(xR)_R \cong (R/I)_R$ for some right ideal $I \subseteq R$ (In fact, $I$ is the right annihilator of $x$). Consequently, $E(xR) \cong E(R/I)$ (isomorphic modules have isomorphic hulls). Hence, $A \cong E(R/I)$, as required.